# Using mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_result together?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am having great trouble trying to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and `mysql_result` together in the same PHP script.

Originally (when not utilizing the `mysql_result` function) I was getting the required database values using a combination of `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` and everything was fine. Then i added 2 lines into my code to obtain certain ‘title’ field values using `mysql_result`.

Now if i run my script as it is below i will only receive 1 result even though there are 2 result.  Then if i move my `do/while` loop up so that it is between the other 2 blocks of code (`mysql_fetch_assoc` and `mysql_result` lines) i will receive the desired 2 results.

I need my loop to come after the `mysql_result` section so putting the loop before it is not an option.

```
// connect to DB and get values
mysql_select_db($database, $mywebsite);
$query_not_related_before = "SELECT  * FROM table  limit 2";
$not_related_before = mysql_query($query_not_related_before, $ mywebsite);
$row_not_related_before = mysql_fetch_assoc($not_related_before);


// Extract just the results from the title field (the problem area!)
$before_essayid4 = mysql_result($not_related_before,0, 'title');
$before_essayid5 = mysql_result($not_related_before,1, 'title');


// Display results etc
do { 
echo "<br />".$row_not_related_before['title']."<br />";} 
while ($row_not_related_before = mysql_fetch_assoc($not_related_before));
```

Plase help,

Many thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get one row because the first already requested here:

```
$row_not_related_before = mysql_fetch_assoc($not_related_before);
```

So I think you have to move result pointer to beginning:

```
mysql_data_seek($not_related_before, 0);
// Display results etc
do { 
echo "<br />".$row_not_related_before['title']."<br />";} 
while ($row_not_related_before = mysql_fetch_assoc($not_related_before));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if this will solve your problem but I think you should "`seek`" the result back.

```
mysql_data_seek ($not_related_before, 0)
```

Also, check out the warning on the **[mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)** page:

> Calls to mysql_result() should not be
> mixed with calls to other functions
> that deal with the result set.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to use 2D array's, i have always found the mysql functions to be a little cumbersome.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query(db_connect(),$query);
$result_out = array();
        if(@mysqli_num_rows($result))
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))$result_out[]=$row;
foreach($result_out as $row)
{
 echo "<br />".$row['title']."<br />"; 
}
?>
```

hth